# JAVAFX- Is it opensource or i have to pay for the buy licence from the opensource?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

Currently, We are thinking to build the application, that runs on the window, mac, and linux.

We are planning to build an app with the rich UI so want to use JavaFX but confuse that we have to buy a license for selling our app? how much will it cost us? which are the feature is available for the OpenJFX?

Answer (score 1):

I found in the [JavaFX-FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/overview/faq-1446554.html#10) that it is under the [Oracle Binary Code License](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/terms/license/index.html).

So you can use it without costs.

Comment: Should I need to buy that to sell my software.

Comment: You can't buy anything, as there are no costs.
Look at the license: "2. LICENSE TO USE. Subject to the terms and conditions of this Agreement including, but not limited to, the Java Technology Restrictions of the Supplemental License Terms, Oracle grants you a non-exclusive, non-transferable, limited license **without license fees to reproduce and use** internally the Software complete and unmodified for the sole purpose of running Programs."

Comment: The JRE itself has some restrictions when it comes to re-distribution: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jre-8-readme-2095710.html when using the javapackager itself (by using it's ant-style call, or via javafx-maven-plugin or javafx-gradle-plugin), these requirements are respected, you will get a stripped JRE included inside your generated package. This might be a thing being mentioned. For the costs itself, as far as I can see, its free ... but I'm no lawyer ;)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to buy a license, it's part of Java 8.